# Visualforce actionRegion doesn't stop page inputField validation

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

actionRegion around the page navigation doesn't stop the input:field standard validations. Using the actionRegion around the selectList is stopping the validation but is not sending the changes variable values back to the controller.

Please suggest if i am miising something.

```
<apex:page showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardController="Meal__c" tabStyle="Meal__c" extensions="MealDetailController" title="Meal Detail">
        <apex:sectionHeader title="Meal Edit" subtitle="{!IF(Meal__c.name != '',Meal__c.name,'New Meal')}"/>
    <apex:form id="form">
                <apex:actionFunction status="LoadStatusPart" name="processFilterChange" action="{!processFilterChange}" rerender="pgBlkData,pgBlkSecSummary"/>
                <apex:actionStatus id="LoadStatusPart">
           <apex:facet name="start">
            <img src="/img/loading.gif" />&nbsp;Please wait. Loading...
           </apex:facet>
        </apex:actionStatus>
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgblk" mode="edit">
                        <apex:pageMessages/>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!saveResult}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Meal Details" columns="2">
                <apex:inputField value="{!meal.Customer__c}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!meal.Status__c}" required="true"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!meal.Date__c}" required="true"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Sumary" columns="2" id="pgBlkSecSummary">
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!!IF(chartDataList.size>0,true,false)}">
                                    <apex:pageMessage summary="No Items have been added to this meal." severity="info" strength="3" />
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(chartDataList.size>0,true,false)}">
                    <apex:chart data="{!chartDataList}" height="100%" width="100%">
                        <apex:pieSeries labelField="name" dataField="data"/>
                        <apex:legend position="right"/>
                    </apex:chart>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!IF(chartDataList.size>0,true,false)}">
                    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!summaryTableProducts}" var="prod">
                        <apex:column >
                            <apex:facet name="header">Name</apex:facet>
                            <apex:outputLink value="/{!prod.Id}" target="_blank">{!prod.name}</apex:outputLink>
                        </apex:column>
                        <apex:column value="{!prod.Grams_of_Protein__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!prod.Grams_of_Fat__c}"/>
                        <apex:column value="{!prod.Grams_of_Carbohydrates__c}"/>
                    </apex:pageBlockTable>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>
                <apex:pageBlockSection title="Meal Options" columns="1" id="pgBlkData">
                                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                        Product Family
                                        **<apex:actionRegion>
                                            <apex:selectList value="{!filterString}" multiselect="false" size="1" id="filterString">
                                                <apex:selectOptions value="{!familyOptions}"/>
<apex:actionSupport event="onchnage" action="{!processFilterChange}" status="LoadStatusPart" rerender="pgblk"/>
                                            </apex:selectList>
                                        </apex:actionRegion>**
                                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!productMenuItemUIList}" var="wrap">
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                                <apex:inputField value="{!wrap.mealItem.Quantity__c}" required="true"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.name}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Product Family</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.family}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Grams of Protein</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.Grams_of_Protein__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Grams of Fat</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.Grams_of_Fat__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Grams of Carbs</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.Grams_of_Carbohydrates__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                            <apex:column >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Quanity Remaining</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputField value="{!wrap.prod2.Quantity_Remaining__c}"/>
                            </apex:column>
                        </apex:pageBlockTable>
                                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="pgBlkSecNavItem">
                                                **<!--<apex:actionRegion>
                                                    <apex:commandButton rendered="{!con.hasPrevious}" value="First">
                                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!navFirst}" rerender="pgblk"/>
                                                    </apex:commandButton>
                                                </apex:actionRegion>
                                                <apex:actionRegion>
                                                    <apex:commandButton rendered="{!con.hasNext}" value="Next">
                                                        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!navNext}" status="LoadStatusPart" rerender="pgblk"/>
                                                    </apex:commandButton>
                                                </apex:actionRegion>-->**
                                                <apex:outputPanel>
                                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!navFirst}" rendered="{!con.hasPrevious}" value="First" rerender="pgBlkData,pgBlkSecSummary"/>
                                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!navPrev}" rendered="{!con.hasPrevious}" value="Previous" rerender="pgBlkData,pgBlkSecSummary"/>
                                                    Page&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!con.pageNumber}"/> of&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!numberOfPages}"/>
                                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!navNext}" rendered="{!con.hasNext}" value="Next" rerender="pgBlkData,pgBlkSecSummary"/>
                                                    <apex:commandButton action="{!navLast}" rendered="{!con.hasNext}" value="Last" rerender="pgBlkData,pgBlkSecSummary"/>
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

When we use  component, the whole form is still submitted, but the only area which is inside actionRegion is processed by the server.